# Fourth Order Nonhomogenous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a fourth order non homogenous differential equation of the form

$$ay^{(4)}+by''+cy=d$$

This actually came from a coupled system of second order non homogenous differential equations, if that is easier to solve:

$$y''=ax+by+c$$
$$x''=dx+fy+g$$

I believe I know how to solve the homogenous form of the fourth order equation, but I don't know how to solve it with the addition of the constant term. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This problem arose from an analysis of a double spring system using Lagrangian mechanics.  You can see an example of the system [here](http://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/double-spring/double-spring-en.html).

Thanks

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ constants?

Comment: Yeah, all letters are constants (other than x and y)

Comment: Use the method of undetermined coefficients (there are countless references to this) to find a particular solution (of the nonhomogeneous equation). Then the solution to the homogeneous equation can be added to the particular solution to give a general solution to the nonhomogeneous equation.